# When mail is sent through outlook desktop app, it creates its own html for template in which some inline styles are present, rest of them are removed

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

It adds display:inline-block on td of html.Here is my code

{{@question__option__no}}
       
       
            {{@question__option__no}}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop edition of Outlook uses Word as an editor for message bodies. You can find supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.